# How to use js-cookie in a TypeScript project?

Tags: node.js, typescript, npm, js-cookie

I want to use the [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) library in my TypeScript project.

First, I installed the library and the typings by running `npm install js-cookie @types/js-cookie --save-dev` in the directory that contains `node_modules` and `package.json`. `package.json` now contains `"@types/js-cookie": "^2.1.0"` and there is a folder `js-cookie` in `node_modules`.

Then I added

```
import * as Cookies from "js-cookie";

[...]

Cookies.remove("token");
```

to my TypeScript file. WebStorm doesn't show any errors.

When I run the server, I get the following error:

```
fetch.js:32 GET http://localhost:8080/ui/js-cookie 404 (Not Found)
common.js:85 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
  Instantiating http://localhost:8080/ui/js-cookie
  Loading http://localhost:8080/ui/src/auth/userStore.tsx
  Loading src/app.tsx
    at fetch.js:37
    at <anonymous>
```

What exactly did I wrong in importing `js-cookie` and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem is normally fixed by using a Task Runner to shift the actual JavaScript file from:

```
./node_modules/js-cookie/js-cookie.js
```

To (for example):

```
./ui/js-cookie.js
```

(Or a location of your choice)

This is because `node_modules` is normally FULL of things you wouldn't want to publish to your web server, so you shift the bits you *do* want to publish into a folder that you will reference at runtime.